# How can i round an Sum in Django ojbect

Tags: python, django

My code:

```
verloningsoverzicht_cumulatief_dagen = 
Overzicht.objects.filter(periode=periode, jaar=jaar) 
            .values('testcontract', 'contract') 
            .annotate(aantal=Sum('aantal'))
```

Now lets say the .annotatie Sum is 6.3500000, i want it rounded to 6.35
The round method is not working, how can i solve this

```
.annotate(aantal=round(Sum('aantal'),2))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of a [**`Round`** expression <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/database-functions/#round):

```
from django.db.models.functions import Round

verloningsoverzicht_cumulatief_dagen = Overzicht.objects.filter(
    periode=periode, jaar=jaar
) .values('testcontract', 'contract').annotate(
    aantal=Round(Sum('aantal'), 2)
)
```

If you use [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2) or earlier, you can work with:

```
from django.db.models import DecimalField, ExpressionWrapper
from django.db.models.functions import Round

verloningsoverzicht_cumulatief_dagen = Overzicht.objects.filter(
    periode=periode, jaar=jaar
) .values('testcontract', 'contract').annotate(
    aantal=ExpressionWrapper(
        Round(Sum('aantal') * 100) / 100,
        output_field=DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    )
)
```

Comment: hi i use django 3.2 but in your second example it rounds to a whole number, i want it rounded with 2 decimals. Is that not possible ?

Comment: @Sander: what if you work with an `ExpressionWrapper`?

Comment: I dont see how i can do the rounding with that ?

Comment: @Sander: you don't *round* with the `ExpressionWrapper`, you specify a different output type, such that Django "parses" the result to the correct type. See edited answer.

Comment: @Sander: what database backend do you use?

Comment: hi, my numbers are always with 2 decimals. So i resolved it in django template with the {{value|floatformat:2}}. It works in this case because i never have more than 2 decimals. You gave the solution (for django 4, so i mark it as closed).